# Html canvas and X Window Id

Tags: xorg, mplayer, html5

I am creating html5 application, and running it using ubuntu-html5-app-container.

The page contains a canvas element.

Is there any possibility to get X window id for the canvas element? As the one to be used with mplayer -wid ID.

This might sound stupid, but I'm planning to play mplayer and render the video on html canvas element.

This application is for private use on ubuntu 14.04, no cross platform support needed.

I have tried to use applet containing awt.canvas, and it worked well. But to run the application, need to sign the applet and applet security settings etc, and also, the most reason can't use this way, ubuntu-html5-app-container seems to be NOT support java applet.

Thanks.